# My Scala methods do not return values to Java code

Tags: java, scala, netbeans, interop

This is a Scala module:

```
package xpf

import java.io.File
import org.jdom.Element
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder

object xmlpf {
  def load_file(filename: String): Element = {
    val builder = new SAXBuilder
    builder.build(new File(filename)).getRootElement
  }
}
```

And here is Java code, calling the method from Scala above:

```
package textxpf;

import org.jdom.Element;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Element root = xpf.xmlpf.load_file("/home/capkidd/proj/XmlPathFinder/Staff.xml");
        System.out.println(root.getName());
    }
}
```

Running java main procedure I see

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at textxpf.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Exploring the problem I found that I cannot return any value of any type from any Scala method to the Java code that called it.

I use NetBeans 6.9.1 with Scala 2.8.1 plugin.
scala-library.jar and jdom.jar are properly plugged to the project.

What am I doing wrong?
Has anybody any idea?

Comment: What is in line 21 of your Main.java?

Comment: The java code you show us has only 10 lines. Please do not post errors you got with different code - post the erros you got with the code you posted.

Comment: sorry, 21st line was before I removed comments from code. The error was emitted by System.out.println(root.getName());

Comment: the error message is now correct

Comment: Mabe you can try to define a java interface SomeInterface with load_file method definition, and then inherit from it in scala like: object xmlpf extends SomeInterface { ...

Comment: Have you tried passing objects from scala methods that are not the result of some complicated external library call? Like defining a simple add method in scala and return a String? Maybe does getRootElement return null?

Comment: could be any number of things, except for what the OP thinks

Comment: Have you tried to run it from command line?

Answer (score 2):

Try this and then debug accordingly:

```
package xpf

import java.io.File
import org.jdom.Element
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder

object xmlpf {
  def load_file(filename: String): Element = {
    val builder = new SAXBuilder
    val re = builder.build(new File(filename)).getRootElement
    if (re == null) throw new NullPointerException("the root element is null!")
    re
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx, but the error message is word to word the same - for Scala this is not the null pointer. more, if I call that method from Scala, not Java, when it is all Scala application - all works well. I'm sure it is the trouble in Java-Scala-interop. but that's all my idea

Comment: Have you made sure your classpath is setup correctly?  On a few occasions I've experienced "impossible" bugs and then discovered that my classpath was screwed up and the code I was compiling wasn't the code I was actually running.  You probably should try it outside of NetBeans were you have control.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar program with no problems:

```
// ms/MyObject.scala
package ms
object myObject {
  def foo(s: String) = s
}

// mj/MyObject2.java
package mj;
public class MyObject2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ms.myObject.foo("hello"));
  }
}
```

I compiled both files, then "scala -cp . mj.MyObject2". Works fine with scala 2.8.1.final. Does this example work in your setup?

So, I wonder if it's some sort of environment issue, such as picking up a stale build of the Scala class? Have you tried a clean build from scratch? Is your runtime class path correct?

Comment: to Dean Wampler: thank you, but my problem is the opposite - I could not run scala code from java. It's amazing, but when I did all from scratch, not using IDE, all worked well. Now I see that I need to tune better my IDE